# count instances with different value in a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

```
a <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
b <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B","A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B")
c <- cbind(a,b)
df <- data.frame(c)
```

What is the simplest way to count distinct elements in a data.frame column?

Comment: Please provide wanted output, it's hard to understand what you mean by "instances", "different value" and "distinct elements"

Comment: `help("table")`. Also, don't use `cbind` if you want a data.frame. Simply do `data.frame(a, b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
> table(df)
   b
a    A  B
  1 12  2
  2  1  1
  3  0  1
  4  1  0

> table(df$a)

 1  2  3  4 
14  2  1  1 

> table(df$b)

 A  B 
14  4
```